# How many docker images can I store in Docker Private Repository

Tags: docker, docker-registry, docker-image, docker-repository

I have created one private repository in docker hub.
My doubts are

1. How many separate images can I store in my single private repository?
2. Is there any image size restriction?
3. When do I need more than one private repository?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Best practice is to use one repository per application. You use different tags to differentiate between versions and flavors of your app. Theoretically you can mix totally different Docker images in one repo. But maybe you can just choose a different Docker repository provider instead that offers more private repositories for free like [Codefresh](https://codefresh.io/docker-registry/free-private-docker-registry/), [GitLab](https://about.gitlab.com/2016/05/23/gitlab-container-registry/) and some others.

Answer (score 14):

1. Each repository can have one docker image only however the image can have many tags so you can have 100 tag. each tag can represent an image if you want to, which gives you a total of 100 in this case same image name but different tags e.g. `myapplication:backend`, `myapplication:frontend`, `myapplication:xservice` and so on. Quoted from the [documentation](https://docs.docker.com/docker-hub/repos/):

   > A single Docker Hub repository can hold many Docker images (stored as tags).
2. Image size restriction is not announced as far as i know but you should keep your image small as you can as the larger it gets the more issues you may face in push and pull so don't make your image 10 GB for example unless there is a must.
3. You may need more than one private repository in case you need to keep each image in a repository.

Comment: It's not the same number of images than number of tags, because one image can have more than 1 tag while it's stored only once. Your answer is good, but he's asking for number of images, so I understand without re-taggering.

Comment: @mulg0r thanks for the tip! I have updated my answer.